# error when using fold function in flink

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-flink, fold, flink-streaming

the code is below:

```scala
env
  .addSource(...)
  .map(r => (0, r))
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(1))
  .fold(mutable.HashSet[String](),(a:(Int,String),b:mutable.HashSet[String])=>a)
```

error occurs during compilation,the error message is:

> Error: missing arguments for method fold in class WindowedStream;
>   follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
>         timeWindow(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(1)).fold(mutable.HashSetString,

but the function defined in class WindowedStream is:

> public  fold(R initialValue, FoldFunction function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is twofold: First of all, the `fold` function expects the `FoldFunction` to be passed in a second parameter list if you're using Scala. Secondly, the first parameter of the `FoldFunction` should be of the aggregating type. Thus, in your case it should be of type `mutable.HashSet[String]`. The following snippet should do the trick:

```
env
  .addSource(...)
  .map(r => (0, r))
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(1))
  .fold(mutable.HashSet[String]()){
    (a: mutable HashSet[String], b: (Int, String)) => a
  }
```

Be aware that the Flink's `fold` API call is deprecated. It's now recommend to use the `aggregate` API call.

Comment: In Flink 1.3, the `aggregate` function on a `WindowedStream` should not be private. Which version are you using?